# Receiver (<BOD.BBRootViewController: 0x7fbe338c1000>) has no segue with identifier 'sw_right'

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

my app is crashing when the app is loading.

These is the method my app is calling:

```
@try
        {
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:SWSegueRightIdentifier sender:nil];
        }
        @catch(NSException *exception) {}
    }
```

& in the Log :

```
Receiver (<BOD.BBRootViewController: 0x7fbe338c1000>) has no segue with identifier 'sw_right'

140454863901800

objc[44313]: pthread_rwlock_rdlock failed (11).
```

What i tried so far : 
1 . I tried to fix it by running "clean" under the "Product" menu in Xcode, and resetting the contents and settings in the simulator. But no luck.

Can you please say what should i need to do overcome that crash.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Check whether you added a segue with identifier `sw_right` in your storyboard.

Comment: Consider the actual error message.  It says you don't have a segue defined for that view controller that matches the given name.  What makes you think that segue exists?

Comment: Hi #Midhun MP & #Phillip Mills, I checked in storyboard. In the Root View Controller i only made connections for sw_rear & sw_front.